# Custom checkBox problem in Visual Studio 2019 using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox

I found on the internet how to create your own checkbox. Unfortunately, there is a problem with the fact that you have to click very slowly to react to a change, and when I click on the text, nothing changes. I presented the whole action in the film. Please help.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6xmVAoUVJ8

Here are the files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10pj6DRjCvfQc8_s0rUufJpN1kdft2sml/view?usp=sharing

CheckBox.cs:

```
class NowyCheckbox : Control
{
    #region Private members

    public bool IsChecked = false;
    private Label CheckBoxLabel;
    private Rectangle CheckBoxRectangle;
    private bool MouseOver = false;

    #endregion

    #region Public Members (in Attributes)

    private Color CheckBoxCharColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

    public Color CheckBoxCharColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxCharColor != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color CheckBoxCharHighlightColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 120, 215);

    public Color CheckBoxCharHighlightColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharHighlightColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxCharHighlightColor != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharHighlightColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Font CheckBoxCharFontValue;

    public Font CheckBoxCharFont
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharFontValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxCharFont != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharFontValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private string CheckBoxCharValue = "!";

    public string CheckBoxChar
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxChar != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }

    private Font CheckBoxFontValue;
    public Font CheckBoxFont
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxFontValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxFont != value)
            {
                CheckBoxFontValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }


    private string CheckBoxTextValue = "Nowy CheckBox";
    public string CheckBoxText
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxTextValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxText != value)
            {
                CheckBoxTextValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }


    private int CheckBoxSizeValue = 12;
    public int CheckBoxSize
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxSizeValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxSize != value)
            {
                CheckBoxSizeValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private int CheckBoxFrameStrengthValue = 1;
    public int CheckBoxFrameStrength
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxFrameStrengthValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxFrameStrengthValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxFrameStrengthValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    #region Public Member


    private int CheckBoxCharOffsetXValue = 0;
    public int CheckBoxCharOffsetX
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharOffsetXValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxCharOffsetX != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharOffsetXValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private int CheckBoxCharOffsetYValue = 0;
    public int CheckBoxCharOffsetY
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxCharOffsetYValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxCharOffsetY != value)
            {
                CheckBoxCharOffsetYValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private int CheckBoxOffsetXValue = 0;
    public int CheckBoxOffsetX
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxOffsetXValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxOffsetX != value)
            {
                CheckBoxOffsetXValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }

    private int CheckBoxOffsetYValue = 0;
    public int CheckBoxOffsetY
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxOffsetYValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxOffsetY != value)
            {
                CheckBoxOffsetYValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Colors
    private Color CheckBoxFrameColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    public Color CheckBoxFrameColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxFrameColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxFrameColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxFrameColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private Color CheckBoxFrameHighlightColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 120, 250);
    public Color CheckBoxFrameHighlightColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxFrameHighlightColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxFrameHighlightColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxFrameHighlightColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private Color CheckBoxBackColorValue = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    public Color CheckBoxBackColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxBackColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxBackColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxBackColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private Color CheckBoxBackHighlightColorValue = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    public Color CheckBoxBackHighlightColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxBackHighlightColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxBackHighlightColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxBackHighlightColorValue = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }


    private Color CheckBoxForeHighlightColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    public Color CheckBoxForeHighlightColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxForeHighlightColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxForeHighlightColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxForeHighlightColorValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }


    private Color CheckBoxForeColorValue = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);
    public Color CheckBoxForeColor
    {
        get
        {
            return CheckBoxForeColorValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (CheckBoxForeColorValue != value)
            {
                CheckBoxForeColorValue = value;
                RefreshLabel();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public NowyCheckbox()
    {

        DoubleBuffered = true;

        Size = new Size(112, 18);

        CheckBoxFont = this.Font;
        CheckBoxCharFont = this.Font;

        var midHeight = 8 - Font.Height / 2;
        CheckBoxLabel = new Label()
        {
            Font = CheckBoxFont,
            Size = new Size(this.Width - 16, this.Height),
            Location = new Point(16, midHeight),
            Text = CheckBoxText
        };

        Controls.Add(CheckBoxLabel);

        CreateMouseEvents();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Create mouse events
    private void CreateMouseEvents()
    {
        MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseEnter(e);
        };

        MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseLeave(e);
        };

        MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseDown(e);
        };



        CheckBoxLabel.MouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseEnter(e);
        };

        CheckBoxLabel.MouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseLeave(e);
        };

        CheckBoxLabel.MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            OnCustomMouseDown(e);
        };
    }
    #endregion

    #region Mouse Events

    private void OnCustomMouseDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        Invalidate();
    }
    private void OnCustomMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseOver == false)
        {
            MouseOver = true;
            Invalidate();

            RefreshLabel();
        }
    }

    private void OnCustomMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MouseOver == true)
        {
            MouseOver = false;
            Invalidate();

            RefreshLabel();
        }
    }




    #endregion

    #region Paint NowyCheckbox

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        PaintRectangle(e);
        if (IsChecked == true)
        {
            PaintArrowChar(e);
        }


    }
    #endregion

    #region Paint NowyCheckboxRectangle
    private void PaintRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var midHeight = Height / 2 - CheckBoxSize / 2;
        CheckBoxRectangle = new Rectangle(0, midHeight, CheckBoxSize, CheckBoxSize);

        var fillColor = MouseOver == true ? CheckBoxBackHighlightColor : CheckBoxBackColor;
        var frameColor = MouseOver == true ? CheckBoxFrameHighlightColor : CheckBoxFrameColor;

        using (var pen = new Pen(frameColor, CheckBoxFrameStrength))
        {
            var brush = new SolidBrush(fillColor);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, CheckBoxRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, CheckBoxRectangle);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Paint Checkbox Arrow
    private void PaintArrowChar(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var charColor = MouseOver == true ? CheckBoxCharHighlightColor : CheckBoxCharColor;

        var midX = CheckBoxSize / 2 - 3 + CheckBoxCharOffsetX;
        var midY = Height / 2 - CheckBoxCharFont.Height / 2 + CheckBoxCharOffsetY;

        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(charColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CheckBoxChar, CheckBoxCharFont, brush, new Point(midX, midY));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region [OnResize]
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        RefreshLabel();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Refresh Label
    private void RefreshLabel()
    {
        if (CheckBoxLabel == null) return;

        CheckBoxLabel.Font = CheckBoxFont;
        CheckBoxLabel.Text = CheckBoxText;
        CheckBoxLabel.ForeColor = MouseOver == true ? CheckBoxForeHighlightColor : CheckBoxForeColor;

        var offsetWidth = Width - CheckBoxSize;
        CheckBoxLabel.Size = new Size(offsetWidth, Height);



        var offsetX = CheckBoxSize + 6 + CheckBoxOffsetX;
        var midHeight = Height / 2 - CheckBoxFont.Height / 2 + CheckBoxOffsetY;
        CheckBoxLabel.Location = new Point(offsetX, midHeight);
        Invalidate();
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void nowyCheckbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nowyCheckbox1.IsChecked)
        {
            label2.Text = "Jestem włączony";
        }
        else
        {
            label2.Text = "Jestem wyłączony";
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            label3.Text = "Jestem włączony";
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "Jestem wyłączony";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace the `IsChecked` **Field** with a public **Property**. In the setter, call a virtual method (say OnCheckedChanged) to invoke a custom event handler (say CheckedChanged). Handle this event in your implementation to do whatever you need whenever the check state changes.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't do it - I don't have the necessary knowledge. If I could ask for an example, I would be grateful.
This is my first program, I wanted it to look nice, I spent a lot of time on it, I've already learned a lot, but it's too much for me. If you would like any compensation, I am able to.
I would like to share the file here for others to use.

Answer (score 1):

An object like your custom check box, should have a mechanism used to notify a subscriber (like a Form) that something has happened. Notifications like mouse clicks, keystrokes, property changes...etc. In [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) programming, your control should generate and *publish* an **event** to be received and handled by a *subscriber* through an **Event Handler**. Your custom control is missing that mechanism and this is the problem.

---

Let's apply that and create a simple check box control.

```cs
[DefaultProperty("Checked")]
[DefaultEvent("CheckedChanged")]
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(CheckBox))]
public class NowyCheckBox : Control
{
```

Class members to keep:

- The bounds of the check box and text areas.
- The points of a check mark.
- The current mouse state.

```cs
    private enum MouseState : int
    {
        None,
        Over,
        Down
    }

    private Rectangle ChkRec, TxtRec;
    private PointF[] ChkPoints;
    private MouseState mouseState = MouseState.None;
```

In the constructor, set the shown below styles to reduce the flickering and to use the control in a container with a background image or gradient colors.

```cs
    public NowyCheckBox() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        UpdateStyles();
    }
```

Add a method to create the drawing objects. Call it from the setters of the relevant properties
(such as `CheckBoxSize`) and methods (like `OnSizeChanged`) as shown next.

```cs
    private void ResetDrawingObjects()
    {
        if (Width == 0 || Height == 0) return;

        ChkRec = new Rectangle(new Point(0, (Height - checkBoxSize.Height) / 2), CheckBoxSize);
        TxtRec = new Rectangle(ChkRec.Right + 5, 0, Width - ChkRec.Right - 10, Height);

        if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
        {
            ChkRec.X = Width - 1 - ChkRec.Width;
            TxtRec.X = ChkRec.X - 5 - TxtRec.Width;
        }

        var r = Rectangle.Inflate(ChkRec, -3, -3);

        ChkPoints = new[]
        {
            new PointF(r.X, r.Y + (r.Height / 2f)),
            new PointF(r.X + (r.Width / 2f) - 1, r.Bottom),
            new PointF(r.Right, r.Y)
        };

        Invalidate();
    }
```

Create a custom event and raise it whenever the `Checked` property changes.

```cs
    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e) => CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
```

Add the properties.

```cs
    private bool _checked;
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Checked
    {
        get => _checked;
        set
        {
            if (_checked != value)
            {
                _checked = value;
                Invalidate();
                OnCheckedChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    private Size checkBoxSize = new Size(12, 12);
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "12, 12")]
    public Size CheckBoxSize
    {
        get => checkBoxSize;
        set { checkBoxSize = value; ResetDrawingObjects(); }
    }

    // Add the rest...
```

Override the following methods to:

- Update the `mouseState` variable and refresh the drawing by calling the `Invalidate` method if needed.
- Call the `ResetDrawingObjects` method whenever the drawing objects need to  resize and/or reposition.
- Like the default `CheckBox` control, toggle the `Checked` property on `Keys.Space` press.
- Draw the control.

```cs
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (mouseState != MouseState.Over)
        {
            mouseState = MouseState.Over;
            // Pass ChkRec to update the checkbox area only.
            Invalidate(ChkRec);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Focus();
            mouseState = MouseState.Down;
            Invalidate(ChkRec);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);

        Checked = !Checked;
        mouseState = MouseState.Over;
        Invalidate(ChkRec);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);

        mouseState = MouseState.None;
        Invalidate(ChkRec);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) Checked = !Checked;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        ResetDrawingObjects();
    }

    protected override void OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRightToLeftChanged(e);
        ResetDrawingObjects();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var g = e.Graphics;

        // Get your colors to fill and draw...
        var clr = mouseState == MouseState.Down
            ? // down color...
            : mouseState == MouseState.Over
            ? // over color...
            : // default color...;

        using (var pn = new Pen(clr)) g.DrawRectangle(pn, ChkRec);

        if (Checked)
        {
            clr = mouseState == MouseState.Down
                ? // down color...
                : mouseState == MouseState.Over
                ? // over color...
                : // default color...;

            using (var pn = new Pen(clr, 2))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.DrawLines(pn, ChkPoints);
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            }

            /*
             * In case you prefere drawing glyphs. Example:
            using (var fnt = new Font("Marlett", 12))
            {
                var r = ChkRec;
                r.Offset(2, -2);

                TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "a", fnt, r, clr,
                    TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter |
                    TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
            }
            */
        }

        var flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis;

        if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Right;
        else
            flags |= TextFormatFlags.Left;

        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Text, Font, TxtRec, ForeColor, flags);
    }
}
```

Put it together, rebuild, drop an instance, double click on it to subscribe to the default event `CheckedChanged`, and handle it as you want.

```cs
private void nowyCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = nowyCheckBox1.Checked
        ? "Jestem włączony"
        : "Jestem wyłączony";
}
```

If you'd like to read more.

[Handle and raise events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)
[C# - Events](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-event)